Voltage across Capacitor in Series after shorting internal capacitor
I have what appears to be a very simple question, but I have not seen it asked anywhere and would like to verify my solution is correct. Imagine that you have 3 capacitors in series, each with an equivalent capacitance value of $C$, with one side initially set to a voltage $V$ and the other side set to ground, GND. The configuration would like something like this:
$$\text{V --|C}_{\text{A}}\text{|--|C}_{\text{B}}\text{|--|C}_{\text{C}}\text{|--GND}$$
As a result, a charge $Q$ will develop on the capacitor $\text{C}_{A}$, where the value of $Q$ is $Q=C_{T}V$, and where the value of $C_{T}$ is the total capacitance of the system which is $C_{T}=C/3$. Therefore $Q=CV/3$. We know that in-between capacitors A & B, and also in-between capacitors B & C a separation of charge will occur, however the node as a whole will stay electrically neutral. Imagine now that we remove the voltage source while keeping the GND connection. The charge distribution will look like the following:
$$\text{(+Q)--|C}_{\text{A}}\text{|-(-Q)--(+Q)-|C}_{\text{B}}\text{|-(-Q)--(+Q)-|C}_{\text{C}}\text{|--(-Q)--GND}$$
Furthermore, now imagine that we temporarily place a wire which connects the node in-between capacitors A & B to the node in-between capacitors B & C, essentially shorting capacitor B. We let the charge distribution equilibrate before removing the wire. The charge distribution would now look like the following:
$$\text{(+Q)--|C}_{\text{A}}\text{|-(-Q)-|C}_{\text{B}}\text{|-(+Q)-|C}_{\text{C}}\text{|--(-Q)--GND}$$
My ultimate question now is, what is the voltage at the left most node (which was originally set to V)?
My proposed solution is that, starting from the GDN connection, we know there will be a positive voltage drop across capacitor C which will be equal to $V_{BC}=Q/C$ and we know that $Q=CV/3$, therefore this equals to $V_{BC}=V/3$. We then know there will be a negative voltage drop across capacitor B such that $V_{AB} = V_{BC}+(-Q)/C=V/3-CV/C3=0$, meaning that node AB will be equal to zero. Then to get the leftmost node, we take the voltage across capacitor A, which is $V_{AB}+Q/C=0+V/3$.
The final solution is therefore that the voltage on the left most node is V/3. Is there anything wrong with this derivation?
EDIT: I am being told this is too much like a "check my work" question. I purposefully presented it like this in order to give sufficient context to what specifically I was asking. In order to satisfy this requirement however, I will ask it in a more vague way, which obfuscates what I am looking to understand:
If 3 capacitors are in series, and equally charged, what happens to the potential drop across the capacitors if we temporarily short the internal capacitor in order to create a separation of charge?

Is GND connected to the other terminal of V?

@BobD yes, assume that initially the voltage source V is relative to GND potential. After the voltage source is removed however, that terminal is left freely floating.

Is or is not the left terminal of V connected DIRECTLY to GND?

@BobD Yes, V is just assumed to be generated by a typical voltage source in this scenario, meaning that the full circuit would be something like GND--(V_src)--V--|CA|--|CB|--|CC|--GND, where I am using "(V_src)" to denote a voltage source that outputs a voltage V.

So...if your source is say a battery,  the right plate of Cc is connected to the negative terminal of the battery and the left plate of Ca is connected to the positive terminal of the battery?

@BobD Yes, that is the initial configuration. Starting from equilibrium, the circuit is then broken (perhaps a switch opens) that results in the left plate of Ca being free floating.
